# Better Way to Assign Multiple Columns in to a 2D array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to grab the values in three different columns and put them in an array. Ideally I'd like to do this all at once, and I'm sure there's a more efficient way...I just can't figure it out. Right now, I'm filtering a table, and want the non-hidden values from three columns in an array. I use three arrays and then later combine them in to one. Is there a better way? Here's how I'm doing it now. Thanks!:

```
Public Function GetPreviousSubmitted2() As Variant()

Dim tblPrevSub As ListObject, tblPastDue As ListObject
Dim arrReturn1() As Variant, arrReturn2() As Variant, arrReturn3() As Variant, rCount As Variant
Dim arrReturn() As Variant

Set tblPastDue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAST DUE LIST").ListObjects("tblPastDue")
Set tblPrevSub = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Previously Submitted").ListObjects("tblPrevSub")

If tblPastDue.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
    tblPastDue.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If

tblPastDue.Range.AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:="0"

rCount = tblPastDue.ListColumns.Item(19).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
ReDim arrReturn(rCount, 2)
arrReturn1 = tblPastDue.ListColumns.Item(19).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
arrReturn2 = tblPastDue.ListColumns.Item(17).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
arrReturn3 = tblPastDue.ListColumns.Item(26).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For i = 1 To rCount
    arrReturn(i, 0) = arrReturn1(i, 1)
    arrReturn(i, 1) = arrReturn2(i, 1)
    arrReturn(i, 2) = arrReturn3(i, 1)
Next


If tblPastDue.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
    tblPastDue.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If

GetPreviousSubmitted2 = arrReturn


End Function
```

Comment: Your current code is not going to work anyway unless all the visible rows are one contiguous range.

Comment: Unfortunately VBA doesnt have many array functions like zip or merge or concat. They also barely have resizable arrays. I think your current method is the best you can do in VBA. Alternatively, you could move all of the desired data to an empty part of the sheet, take the values into an array, and then clear the data. It would save you the loop, but its likely slower than looping.

Comment: If you have a newer version or subscription, you might try CHOOSECOLS and CHOOSEROWS functions in a formula and then read that spill range.

Comment: Luckily there is always a value in each cell on this sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through row by row assign each of the three arrays into a new worksheet in adjacent columns, then read that range back again into the final array. E.G.

```
Dim a1 As Variant, a2 As Variant, a3 As Variant
a1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A2769")
a2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C2769")
a3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E2:E2769")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))

ws.Range("A1:A" & UBound(a1) + 1).Value = a1
ws.Range("B1:B" & UBound(a2) + 1).Value = a2
ws.Range("C1:C" & UBound(a3) + 1).Value = a3

Dim finalarr As Variant
finalarr = ws.Range("A1:C" & UBound(a1)).Value

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

If the arrays are different sizes then capture the maximum size of the three and use that size eg `finalarr = ws.Range("A1:C" & maxsize).Value`

Edit: This should be incredibly fast to execute even with creating the additional worksheet

Answer (score 1):

Not professional in the least, but it works for *unfiltered* ranges:

```
Function test(ByVal Target as Range, ParamArray Cols())
    Dim vOut, tmp, tmp1, i&
    ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(Cols) + 1)

    For Each tmp In Cols
        i = i + 1
        tmp1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
            WorksheetFunction.Index(Target, Empty, tmp).Value2 _
            )
        vOut(i) = tmp1
    Next tmp

    test = vOut
End Function
```

In the worksheet `=Transpose(Test(A1#,1,3,5))`
You'll get the 1st, 3rd, 5th columns of the input array. Tried transposing in the VBA, but it bombed.

The problem with filtered ranges is that you have to iterate `.Area`s; each `Area` is one contiguous block of visible cells.